# Issue with date ranges gathering data from Analytics api

Tags: php, google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I'm trying to get data from analytics via ecommerce reports. The thing is no matter what start date I use from a certain period length, it allways gives me the same data, and I need to retrieve information about Conversion rates 90 days in the past from now.

Setting date range from `90daysAgo - yesterday` gives me the exact same results as `72-daysAgo - yesterday`, so data does not change if I increase NdaysAgo from 72 days. It's like if it had some limitation.

Have tried to tweak sampling level and so, but it's not the problem, and documentatition does not talk about these kind of limitations.

My request is something as follows:

```
$dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
$dateRange ->setStartDate("90daysAgo");
$dateRange ->setEndDate("yesterday");

//Dimensions
$category= new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
$category->setName("ga:productCategoryHierarchy");
$brand= new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
$brand->setName("ga:productBrand");

//Metrics
$uniquePurchases= new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
$uniquePurchases->setExpression("ga:uniquePurchases");
$productDetailViews= new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
$productDetailViews->setExpression("ga:productDetailViews");


$request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
$request->setViewId("XXXX");
$request->setDateRanges($dateRange);
$request->setDimensions(array($category, $brand));
$request->setMetrics(array($uniquePurchases, $productDetailViews));
```

Have any clue about what could be happening? Btw, Changing dateRanges format (to YYYY-MM-DD for example) does not solve the problem. These data is perfectly shown in Analytics backoffice for the same date range.

Comment: How many results do you get with 90 days and 72 days? Just making sure the data is not paginated.

Comment: I'm getting 1296 results, but i'm taking into account pagination an even setting pagesize to 10k, so unless i'm doing it wrong, that's not the issue =(.

Comment: I found I have the exact same problem when testing my api call via https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/ , no matter how many days I increase after 72 days before yesterday in the past, I allways get the same (wrong) result.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, It was all my mistake. I didn´t know **Analytics views do only collect data since the creation of the view**. The problem was The view i was using in my api calls was a newer one so it only had data from June 19th and those were the 7X days in the past.

Hope if someone falls into the same mistake finds this useful.